# Bootstrap dropdown is not showing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the problem with this code below..
everything is working except menu drop down.

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner" > 
    <div class="container">     
        <ul class="nav">  
            <li class="dropdown">  
                <a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">  Services  <b class="caret"></b>  </a>  
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Web development</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Wordpress Theme development</a></li>  
                </ul>  
            </li>  
        </ul>  
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li ><a href="javascript:;" style="font-size:17px; color: rgb(11, 0, 134);">  Hello, <?php echo "Admin"; ?>     </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you included the js files and jquery?

Comment: Dont see any issues http://jsfiddle.net/s263V/ Have you included the necessary files?

Comment: both bootstrap.js and Jquery are included..

Comment: Are they included in the right order? Are you including jquery first?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a  at the bottom. Otherwise everything seems to be fine.